# An error with Erlang router

Tags: erlang, router, mochiweb

I try to make a comet-server using Mochiweb like [there](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-2).

If I do it from erlang shell, it's alright.

But If try to start 1st node with mochiweb from command line:

```
erl -pa ebin edit deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -sname n1 -s server +K true -setcookie secret_key -s reloader
```

And 2nd one with router:

```
erl -pa ebin edit deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -sname router -setcookie secret_key -eval 'net_adm:ping(n1@localhost), router:start_link().'
```

If I connect to mochiweb from browser I have this error

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 18-Jul-2012::19:04:45 ===
crasher:
initial call: mochiweb_acceptor:init/3
pid: <0.73.0>
registered_name: []
exception exit: {noproc,
                    {gen_server,call,
                        [undefined,{login,"234567e",<0.73.0>}]}}
  in function  gen_server:call/2
  in call from server_web:loop/2
  in call from mochiweb_http:headers/5
ancestors: [server_web,server_sup,<0.55.0>]
messages: []
links: [<0.57.0>,#Port<0.1406>]
dictionary: [{mochiweb_request_qs,
                  [{"session_id","234567e"},{"obj_id","page"}]},
              {mochiweb_request_path,"/polling"}]
trap_exit: false
status: running
heap_size: 2584
stack_size: 24
reductions: 1516
```

I think that problem is in this string from router.erl:

```
-define(SERVER, global:whereis_name(?MODULE)).
```

Because first part of -eval (**net_adm:ping(n1@localhost)**) was started without errors and I could see **n1@localhost** in **nodes().**. But the second part of -eval (**router:start_link()**) was not available for **?MODULE**.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **gen_server** that was supposed to be globally registered with name of current module (?MODULE is replaced with it) just has not been started yet. **global:whereis_name(?MODULE)** will return **undefined** right in this case, like you see in log you posted.

Find the part of your code that's supposed to do that (by grepping for ?MODULe and/or gen_server:start_link in that module) and make sure it was executed on the first node.